# How to handle events in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events

As I understand it HTML is a mark-up language to easily exchange and render data on someone's computer by the internet from other people's computer.

It was a language that acts on DOM (Document Object Model) to provide some functionality to the other user like to render a webpage or handling events.

The problem with html is that when http request is made by a user to the http server, the http server will close the connection after it give the response to the user.

So, my question is what happen if the html file accepts a user input like `onclick` attribute of the html? does the event will be stored in a database somewhere like SQL, mongoDB or is it just purely DOM(meaning DOM can handle the event, like maybe DOM has its own database?)?

so let say if we want to navigate from one html file into another html file if the user click a button. But the in the first html file there is two buttons with its respective two images.

The second html file is the one to be rendered when clicking occur. How to make the second html file render the correct images based on the user input in the first html file? do I need a database? or does the event get stored in the DOM's database if there is any.

Comment: HTML doesn't require the internet; you can open a HTML file on your computer offline. It doesn't act on the DOM, that's JavaScript. Changes JavaScript make to the DOM are stored in the browser's application memory.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: HTML navigation is achieved through anchor tags `<a href="page2.html">`. What is rendered in that page is down to either the static contents of the HTML file, any server-generated content or dynamic content retrieved or generated by JavaScript after the page loads in the browser

Comment: @ceejayoz maybe my question is little bit confusing and i don't want to annoy you too much. I was thinking it fast forward when i already have the website hosted somewhere. So i need to understand how an online version of html work..i.e how one html file communicate with other html file

Comment: i know that nooby like me will ask a a very confusing question as myself was confusing with that topic too. That's the reason the question is being asked. To correct some confusion in my mind. I rather ask a very basic question first before asking a very focus question. Because then i would forgot or does not understand it if some other situations that i want to do. If anybody think this is bad question and will not help others its up to you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Pass the respective image  as a query parameter when navigating on page 2 as shown below.

```html
<button onClick="page2.html?image=image1">Image 1</button>
<button onClick="page2.html?image=image2">Image 2</button>
```

Read the query parameter on page 2 and render the image according to the value of query parameter. The query parameter can be read as below.

```
const queryString = window.location.search;

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
```

Comment: ok now i understand this. When the website is hosted somewhere, it will have it's own identifier i.e a `url` which is like a file path. So JavaScript code have the functions capable of getting what is happening in the html file i.e capturing a user input from that html file and give the output accordingly. So in a nutshell, the one responsible to store the event is the DOM

Comment: What is `onClick="page2.html?image=image1"` expected to do?

Comment: it means it will check inside `page2.html` whether the image being clicked was `image1` i guess

Comment: @beginner The `onClick` attributes can't be an URL. It has to be JavaScript. This button causes an error. The code in this answer isn't correct.